# Cosmosdb store procedure get less documents than real

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am preparing store procedure on cosmosdb by Javascript, however, it gets less documents than the real number of documents in collection.

The sproc is called by C#, C# pass a parameter "transmitterMMSI" which is also the partition key of this collection.

First, the following query is executed in sproc:

```
var query = 'SELECT COUNT(1) AS Num FROM AISData a WHERE a.TransmitterMMSI="' + transmitterMMSI + '"';
```

The result is output in response, and the value is 5761, which is the same as the real number of documents in collection.

However, when I change the query to the following:

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM AISData a WHERE a.TransmitterMMSI="' + transmitterMMSI + '"';
```

The documents.length is output as 5574, which is smaller than the real number.

I have already changed the **pageSize: -1**, which should mean unlimited.

I did some search with google and stack overflow, it seems that **continuation** can be help. However, I tried some examples, and they don't work.

Anyone familiar with this can help?

The following list the scripts.

The sproc js script is here, which is also the file "DownSampling.js" used in the C# code:

```
function DownSampling(transmitterMMSI, interval) {
var context = getContext();
var collection = context.getCollection();
var response = context.getResponse();
var receiverTime;
var tempTime;
var groupKey;
var aggGroup = new Object();

var query = 'SELECT * FROM AISData a WHERE a.TransmitterMMSI="' + transmitterMMSI + '"';
var accept = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), query, { pageSize: -1},
    function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
        if (err) throw new Error("Error" + err.message);

        // Find the smallest deviation comparting to IntervalTime in each group
        for (i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
            receiverTime = Date.parse(documents[i].ReceiverTime);
            tempTime = receiverTime / 1000 + interval / 2;
            documents[i].IntervalTime = (tempTime - tempTime % interval) * 1000;
            documents[i].Deviation = Math.abs(receiverTime - documents[i].IntervalTime);

            // Generate a group key for each group, combinated of TransmitterMMSI and IntervalTime
            groupKey = documents[i].IntervalTime.toString();
            if (typeof aggGroup[groupKey] === 'undefined' || aggGroup[groupKey] > documents[i].Deviation) {
                aggGroup[groupKey] = documents[i].Deviation;
            }
        }

        // Tag the downsampling
        for (i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
            groupKey = documents[i].IntervalTime;
            if (aggGroup[groupKey] == documents[i].Deviation) {
                documents[i].DownSamplingTag = 1;
            } else {
                documents[i].DownSamplingTag = 0;
            }

            // Remove the items that are not used
            delete documents[i].IntervalTime;
            delete documents[i].Deviation;

            // Replace the document
            var acceptDoc = collection.replaceDocument(documents[i]._self, documents[i], {},
                function (errDoc, docReplaced) {
                    if (errDoc) {
                        throw new Error("Update documents error:" + errDoc.message);
                    }
                });
            if (!acceptDoc) {
                throw "Update documents not accepted, abort ";
            } 
        } 
        response.setBody(documents.length);
    });
if (!accept) {
    throw new Error("The stored procedure timed out.");
}
}
```

And the C# code is here:

```
    private async Task DownSampling()
    {
        Database database = this.client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == DatabaseId).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
        DocumentCollection collection = this.client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(database.SelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == AISTestCollectionId).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

        string scriptFileName = @"..\..\StoredProcedures\DownSampling.js";
        string scriptId = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(scriptFileName);

        var sproc = new StoredProcedure
        {
            Id = scriptId,
            Body = File.ReadAllText(scriptFileName)
        };

        await TryDeleteStoredProcedure(collection.SelfLink, sproc.Id);
        sproc = await this.client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync(collection.SelfLink, sproc);

        IQueryable<dynamic> query = this.client.CreateDocumentQuery(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, AISTestCollectionId),
            new SqlQuerySpec()
            {
                //QueryText = "SELECT a.TransmitterMMSI FROM " + AISTestCollectionId + " a",
                QueryText = "SELECT a.TransmitterMMSI FROM " + AISTestCollectionId + " a WHERE a.TransmitterMMSI=\"219633000\"",
            }, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1, MaxBufferedItemCount = -1 });

        List<dynamic> transmitterMMSIList = query.ToList(); //TODO: Remove duplicates
        Console.WriteLine("TransmitterMMSI count: {0}", transmitterMMSIList.Count());
        HashSet<string> exist = new HashSet<string>();

        foreach (var item in transmitterMMSIList)
        {
            //int transmitterMMSI = Int32.Parse(item.TransmitterMMSI.ToString());
            string transmitterMMSI = item.TransmitterMMSI.ToString();

            if (exist.Contains(transmitterMMSI))
            {
                continue;
            }
            exist.Add(transmitterMMSI);
            Console.WriteLine("TransmitterMMSI: {0} is being processed.", transmitterMMSI);
            var response = await this.client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<string>(sproc.SelfLink,
                new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(transmitterMMSI) }, transmitterMMSI, 30);
            string s = response.Response;
            Console.WriteLine("TransmitterMMSI: {0} is processed completely.", transmitterMMSI);
        }
    }

    private async Task TryDeleteStoredProcedure(string collectionSelfLink, string sprocId)
    {
        StoredProcedure sproc = this.client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collectionSelfLink).Where(s => s.Id == sprocId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
        if (sproc != null)
        {
            await client.DeleteStoredProcedureAsync(sproc.SelfLink);
        }
    }
```

I tried to comment the 2 loops in the JS codes, only the **documents.length** output, while the response number is still less. However, I changed the query to **SELECT a.id**, the **documents.length** is correct. Looks like it is the continuation issue.

Answer (score 0):

The sproc is probably timing out. To use a continuation token in these circumstances, you will need to return it to your C# calling code then make another call to the sproc passing in your token. If you show us your sproc code we can help more.

Comment: Looking at your sproc code, it's not considered good practice in javascript to embed a call to an async operation (`replaceDocument()`) inside of an unbounded loop. This will rapidly launch a bunch of async operations that will need to be left open and may exceed resources. It's better to create a stack of operations and then in an async fashion pop things off that queue in batches. That could be your problem.

Comment: I have already tried commenting the replace part in the jacascript,  only to execute the query and no loop, and set documents.length in response, however, it still get less number than real. Looks like still the continuation problem. Besides, you mentioned "in an async fashion pop things off that queue", I don't very follow that, can you explain more detailed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a continuation token to make repeated calls to queryDocuments() from within the sproc without additional roundtrips to the client. Keep in mind that if you do this too many times your sproc will eventually timeout, though. In your case, it sounds like you're already very close to getting all of the documents you're seeking so maybe you will be OK.

Here is an example of using a continuation token within a sproc to query multiple pages of data:

```
function getManyThings() {

    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var query = {
        query: 'SELECT r.id, r.FieldOne, r.FieldTwo FROM root r WHERE r.FieldThree="sought"'
    };

    var continuationToken;
    getThings(continuationToken);

    function getThings(continuationToken) {
        var requestOptions = {
            continuation: continuationToken,
            pageSize: 1000 // Adjust this to suit your needs
        };
        var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), query, requestOptions, function (err, feed, responseOptions) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            for (var i = 0, len = feed.length; i < len; i++) {                
                var thing = feed[i];
                // Do your logic on thing...
            }
            if (responseOptions.continuation) {
                getThings(responseOptions.continuation);
            }
            else {
                var response = getContext().getResponse();
                response.setBody("RESULTS OF YOUR LOGIC");
            }
        });
        if (!isAccepted) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody("Server rejected query - please narrow search criteria");
        }
    }
}
```